# Start each Layout with the same LinearLayout automatically

Tags: android

I Have simple question, i Have some linear layout with buttons on it.
how can I make this linear layout share to all my application layouts without copy it to the beginning of each layout.
I mean that any xml layout will start from the same LinearLayout, and will share the same references , like browser bar but when I launch to another Activity it's still visible.

Thank's guys

Comment: That sounds like an ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the include tag in each of your layouts

```
<include android:id="@+id/layout_id" layout="@layout/my_layout" />
```

see this blog post http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/